# Fixed Point Arithmetics in VHDL on Vivado 2018

Tags: math, binary, vhdl, fixed-point, vivado

Hi I would like to ask on how to perform fixed point arithmetics in VHDL on VIVADO 2018. I have been following so many threads but I am struggling to understand the responses from other users. I am new to this field and I can't really understand some of the technical terms that well.

I believe there is a library known as fixed_pkg but I am not sure how to add it into the VIVADO compiler so that it can be recognised.

I would really appreciate your kind help!

Comment: See [Cannot find fixed_pkg in IEEE or IEEE_PROPOSED](https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Synthesis/Cannot-find-fixed-pkg-in-IEEE-or-IEEE-PROPOSED/td-p/718272).

Comment: For -2008 package fixed_pkg is found in library ieee. Earlier VHDL revisions  it would be found in a different library or would be analyzed into a user resource library. See [Vivado Synthesis User Guide 901](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2018_2/ug901-vivado-synthesis.pdf#nameddest=xFixedPointSupport) and [Logic Simulation User Guide 900](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2018_2/ug900-vivado-logic-simulation.pdf#nameddest=xVHDL2008SupportInVivadoSimulator). XSIM doesn't support generic packages requiring a non-standard implementation.